# using all ASCII chars in Huffman tree

Tags: image-processing, compression, huffman-code

i'm using Huffman algorithm to compress images.

the problem is all ASCII characters are used in images ,so there is no char for the root node.
How can i handle this case ?

Comment: In addition to what the answer mentions, the alphabet size isn't limited to just 256 symbols. e.g. DEFLATE uses a 288-symbol tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The internal nodes of a Huffman tree (including the root) do not correspond to any symbol, so no character needs to be reserved for them.

If for technical reasons the internal nodes have an unnecessary symbol field, you can leave that unassigned or zero of anything else of your choice, it would not affect anything because that value will never be used.